# Ionic Angular directive to update radio field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have a radio button set in an ionic app that represent a group of answers to a test question.

Controller:

```
$scope.question = {
 answers: [
   {
     id:  21,
     answer: "Chicago"
   },
   {
    id: 22,
    answer: "New York"
   },
   {
    id: 23,
    answer: "Los Angeles"
  }
]};
```

This in HTML:

```
  <ion-radio ng-repeat="answer in question.answers"
             ng-value="answer.id"
             ng-model="answerData.selectedAnswer"
            class="radio-positive">
    {{ answer.answer }}
  <div class="radio-right">{{some_scope_value[answer.id]}}</div>
  </ion-radio>
```

Assume the question is "What city is in California", I want to highlight that radio selecction with "Correct" if it's chosen. If one of the others is chosen, I want that to be labeled "Wrong" and the correct answer to be labeled "Answer". These should be located to the right and on the same line, using this div:

```
<div class="radio-right">{{Correct!" || "Wong" || "Answer}}{{some_scope_value[answer.id]}}</div>
```

My question is: does this require a directive to access the "some_scope_value[answer.id]"?? I realize that the [answer.id] brackets are not legit. I just show that to illustrate the concept of accessing that field based on the answer.id.

**UPDATE:** So if the user selects "Chicago" or "New York", then the word "Wrong" should show next to "Chicago" or "New York", **and** "This is the right answer" should show next to "Los Angeles".

But if the use selects "Los Angeles", then "CORRECT!" should show next to "Los Angeles" and nothing else should display on the other two lines.

Also, this should all happen on a button click, not on answer select (so the user can change their mind before submitting their answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you dont need a directive to make that work.**

To achieve this you can simplify your answer result handling by not using indexed (array/objects). You can use, `ng-class`, `ng-show` or `ng-if` to visual the right answer.

#### Controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.selectedValue = {
      answer: ''
    };

  $scope.questions = {
    answers: [{
        id: 21,
        answer: "Chicago"
      }, {
        id: 22,
        answer: "New York"
      }, {
        id: 23,
        answer: "Los Angeles"
      }
    ]
  };
});
```

#### View

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions.answers">
          <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedValue.answer" value="{{ question.answer }}">
          {{ question.answer }}<br/>
          </label>
      </div>

      <p>{{ selectedValue.answer }}</p>
      <p ng-show="selectedValue.answer === 'Chicago'"> Right answer!!! </p>
      <p ng-show="selectedValue.answer !== 'Chicago'"> Wrong answer!!! </p>
</div>
```

Here is a also a plunker [plunker](https://plnkr.co/l923YJ).

#### Different handling by array

If you realy want to search `id` in `$scope.questions.answers` I should preffer using [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

```
var indexFoundById= lodash.findIndex($scope.questions.answers, function (chr) {
      return chr.id== selectedId;
});

//result handling
console.log($scope.questions.answers[indexFoundById].answer); //Chicago
```

#### Different handling by objects - [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/zJyFsx?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.selectedValue = {
      answerId: null
    };


  $scope.questions = {
    answers: {
      21 :{
        right: true,
        answer: "Chicago"
      }, 
      22: {
        right: false,
        answer: "New York"
      }, 
      23 :{
        right: false,
        answer: "Los Angeles"
      }
    }
  };
});
```

#### View

```
 <div ng-repeat="(questionId, question) in questions.answers">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedValue.answerId" value="{{ questionId }}"> {{ question.answer }}
      <span style="color:green;" ng-show="questionId === selectedValue.answerId && questions.answers[selectedValue.answerId].right === true"> Right answer!!! </span>
      <span style="color:red;" ng-show="questionId === selectedValue.answerId && questions.answers[selectedValue.answerId].right !== true"> Wrong answer!!! </span>
      <br/>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear about how to present the results  next to the options. By hard coding "Chicago" your answer doesn't show how to do what I need. But it shows promise.

Comment: @lilbiscuit, please check the "lodash" part on the bottom of my answer. Thats how you can select the right answer in a not associative array. Handling associative arrays in JavaScript is not recommended. Else you can use a object like `$scope.answers { 22: true, 23: false, 1235: false}`.

Comment: @lilbiscuit I added 3 examples how to handle this. Does one approach hit?

Comment: check the question update for more specifics. The ansers object is coming from a server and I don't want to include any question data in it. I have the correct answer ID already in a questions object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a directive. You can do it like this:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.question = {
 answers: [
   {
     id:  21,
     answer: "Chicago"
   },
   {
     id: 22,
     answer: "New York"
   },
   {
     id: 23,
     answer: "Los Angeles"
   },
 correct_id: 21    
]};
```

**View:**

```
<ion-radio ng-repeat="answer in question.answers"
         ng-value="answer.id"
         ng-model="answerData.selectedAnswer"
        class="radio-positive">
{{ answer.answer }}
<div class="radio-right" ng-show="answerData.selectedAnswer == question.correct_id">Right!</div>
</ion-radio>
```

Comment: This shows "Right!"  next to all three answers when the correct answer is selected.